# Is it possible to have drag n drop short list like iPhone bookmark in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm wondering if drag n drop short list like the functionality of iPhone bookmark possible in Sencha touch 2.

I've searched through many sencha touch Q&A but didn't find any suitable answer.

This code makes list draggable but only works for top to bottom. Can't drag any item from bottom of the list to up.

```
var selEl = dataview.element.down("." + dataview.getSelectedCls());
var d = new Ext.util.Draggable({
    element: selEl,
    listeners: {
        dragstart: function(self, e, startX, startY) {
            console.log("test dragStart[" + startX + ":" + startY + "]");
        },
        drag: function(self, e, newX, newY) {
            console.log("test drag[" + newX + ":" + newY + "]");
        },
        dragend: function(self, e, endX, endY) {
            console.log("test dragend[" + endX + ":" + endY + "]");
        }
    }
});
```

is it possible to have shortable list in sencha touch 2?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to do this using the code from this example: https://github.com/kostysh/Drag-Drop-example-for-Sencha-Touch

Comment: I've seen that codes and that is not what i want. Please read the question carefully before answering. I want drag and short list like in iPhone bookmark. If you have iPhone then check the safari bookmark and you'll understand.